# Admin Privileges Required When They Shouldn't Be Needed

Tags: batch-file, admin

I have written a simple ping batch file and it will not run from the desktop unless it is run as administrator.

It has been tried on windows 10 1709, 1809 and 1903.  If it is run from a network location it seems to work as expected.

```
echo %errorlevel% 1
ping -t 8.8.8.8
echo %errorlevel% 2
:eof
```

It seems to get to error level marked "1" and then loops back on it's self.  The error level is 0.  It never gets to the error level marked "2".  If the `@echo off` is removed the command can be seen to loop over and over until the batch is terminated.  Though when ran as administrator it works fine. This was happening with a simple `choice` batch too.

````
C:\Users\test\Desktop>echo 0 1
0 1

C:\Users\test\Desktop>ping -t 8.8.8.8

C:\Users\test\Desktop>echo 0 1
0 1

C:\Users\test\Desktop>ping -t 8.8.8.8

C:\Users\test\Desktop>echo 0 1
0 1

C:\Users\test\Desktop>ping -t 8.8.8.8

C:\Users\test\Desktop>echo 0 1
0 1

C:\Users\test\Desktop>ping -t 8.8.8.8

C:\Users\test\Desktop>echo 0 1
0 1

C:\Users\test\Desktop>ping -t 8.8.8.8

C:\Users\test\Desktop>echo 0 1```
````

Comment: Simple: don't name your script `ping.bat`...

Comment: Well, now I feel a little silly.  I imagine my choice file was named choice.bat too.  Doh!!  Thank you so much